# Matrix multiplication: does product with vector imply equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an equation of the form
$$AX = BCX$$

where $A,B,C$ are all $n \times n$ matrices, and $X$ is an $n \times 1$ vector. (In my case, $n=9$, but this question applies more generally.)

Is it always the case that $A=BC$, or are there some exceptions?

**Additional question:**
If A is $n\times n$, $B$ is $n\times m$, and $C$ is $m\times n$, do you get the same answer as above? (i.e. $A=BC$)

Comment: If X is a particular vector, the answer is no. If the equality holds for any vector X, the answer (to both questions) is yes.

Comment: First, if $X$ is the null vector, in your case, $X = \vec{0} = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ then $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be anything. Second, if any of $B$ and/or $C$ are singular, in this case (square matrices), they have zero determinant, then $A$ cannot be the identity matrix.

Comment: Your equation holds if and only if $X$ belongs to the kernel of $A-BC$.

Comment: How can you tell if $A$ belongs to the kernel of $A-BC$?

Comment: I guess you are asking what a kernel looks like. It has a Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra).

Comment: Sorry I meant: how do you tell if *$X$* belongs in the kernel of $A-BC$? Do you have to do Gaussian elimination to establish this? (And under what conditions do *all* $X$ belong in the kernel?)

Comment: It is easy to test whether $X$ belongs to the kernel; by definition it is when $\left(A-BC\right)X=0$. And as lisyarus suggested, that all $X$ belong to the kernel means that $A-BC=0$.